# Filling k positions with objects from $n$ different types

Tags: combinatorics, permutations

There are $n$ different types of objects and $k$ positions where an object can be placed. How can I determine the number of ways in which these $k$ positions can be filled by using objects of these $n$ types?

Any number of objects from a given type can be used and two objects of the same type are indistinguishable.

Comment: In each position is there to be just one object ?

Answer (score 3):

You have $n$ different options for each of $k$ positions, and they're all independent, so by the [multiplication principle](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rule_of_product) there are $n^k$ possibilities.